# Options how to give feedback to user of SPA website after AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, single-page-application

I have SPA website built in React.js. What are the options to inform user of this website when AJAX calls from different user interactions are successfull/failed/pending?

I only know about Toastr styled messages in corner of website, but those seems spammy and unconvinient to me:

**Google Console: (Bottom center)**

[image]

**Commonly used toastr lib: (Commonly right top)**

[image]

Are there any other commonly used possibilities?

**Example of what I mean by user interaction AJAX calls:**

When user click on green "Check" button, state of current row will be asynchronously changed (AJAX call to update row state). AJAX can be successfull or unsuccessfull. How to inform user that state was changed or was not changed? (I also disable check button, when success, but some users can miss it)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to wire up some sort of HttpInterceptor. I'm not sure how you are making your HTTP requests, but libraries like axios support this concept. Angular does as well, but you're using react.

- https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept

Here is an example of how I do it in angular. Basically, I use the HttpInterceptor to apply jwt credentials and give user feedback via snackbar (toast) if something goes wrong. If you are working with a reputable HTTP library, you should be able to convert this into their HTTP interceptor setup.

```
intercept( _request: HttpRequest<any>, _next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this._store.select(state => state.authState?.token).pipe(
        take(1),
        exhaustMap( token => {
            const req = token ? _request.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`})
            }) : _request.clone();
            return _next.handle(req).pipe(
                catchError( (_error: any, _caught: any) => {
                    switch ( _error.status ) {
                        case 400:
                            if (_error.error && _error.error !== '') {
                                this._uiService.showSnackbar(_error.error);
                            } else {
                                this._uiService.showSnackbar(`400: Bad Request`);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 401:
                            this._router.navigateByUrl('/login').then();
                            break;
                        case 403:
                            this._uiService.showSnackbar('Access Denied');
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            this._uiService.showSnackbar(_error.error || `404: Resource not found`);
                            break;
                        case 500:
                            if (_error.error && _error.error !== '') {
                                this._uiService.showSnackbar(`Exception: ${_error.message}`, 30);
                            } else {
                                this._uiService.showSnackbar(`500: An error occurred on the server`);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return of(_error);
                })
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: This is nice :) Thanks. But I was not asking about this. I was asking more about actual UI possibilities and approaches.